# How to transfer selected Mesh onto another area on the same Mesh

Tags: mesh

I'm trying to to transfer the selected mesh into the designated area its a curved surface and its making it hard for me to get it in place. What method would be best to get it in place?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your topology is probably not the best but you can have a good result nevertheless:

[image]

Just duplicate the part you want to copy, mirror it, rotate it a bit so that it can fit the hole correctly, join the vertices with the *Snapping* and *Auto Merge* options:

[image]

Also don't forget to recalculate the normals. It still won't look perfect but you can duplicate the vertices all around the (former) hole, separate this mesh as a new object, grid fill to create a plane:

[image]

Now you can use this plane as the target of a *Shrinkwrap* with these selected vertices as group so that only them stick to the target:

[image]

Then apply the *Shrinkwrap*, activate the *Subdivision Surface*.